# How can I focus an input that's sliding in from off the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onfocus

I have an element (`#cols`) that's 3x wider than the `<body>`. It has 3 columns, each of which is exactly as wide as `<body>`. Clicking a button slides the `#cols` element over by the width of one column and simultaneously focuses the `<input>` in the column that's sliding into view:

http://jsbin.com/puhurakewa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

The problem, as you can see from the demo, is that focusing the input causes weird behavior. I believe the browser says,

> "*Crap*, the user focused an input that's off-screen. I need to show it!"

and then magically scrolls the input into view. This breaks the transition.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? It's extremely undesirable. I've noticed it in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on my Mac.

EDIT: Thank you for the answers so far. I should have been more specific with my question. I'm aware that I can "work around" this issue by waiting for the animation to end, but what I'm curious about is how to work *through* this issue and focus the input immediately. It's a better experience, because users can begin typing before the transition is over.

Comment: _"It's a better experience, because users can begin typing before the transition is over."_ -- My thoughts exactly. I'm curious though, have you managed to figure this out by now? I'm facing the same problem at this very moment (of course if I come up with a solution, I'll post it right away).

Comment: @JohnWhite No, I just gave up on the sliding transition.

Answer (score 1):

Add the focus event after transition ends

```
 $('#cols').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function() {
      $input.focus();
  });
```

[JSbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/hozibomera/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already using Jquery might as well leverage the animate method, then on the complete function you focus the input, for more info check out the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Heres the JS (this works perfectly, but spend some time neatening it up/refactoring if you wish):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('button').on('click', function () {

  var colId = $('.showing').attr('id');

    if(colId == "col-1"){
      $('#cols').animate({
          right: '200px'
      }, 1000, "swing", function(){
          $("#col-2").find('input').focus();
          $('#col-1').removeClass('showing');  
          $('#col-2').addClass('showing');              
      });
    }
    else if(colId == "col-2"){
      $('#cols').animate({
          right: '400px'
      }, 1000, "swing", function(){
          $("#col-3").find('input').focus();
          $('#col-2').removeClass('showing');  
          $('#col-3').addClass('showing');                    
      });          
    }
    else if(colId == "col-3"){
      $('#cols').animate({
          right: '0px'
      }, 1000, "swing", function(){
          $("#col-1").find('input').focus();
          $('#col-3').removeClass('showing');  
          $('#col-1').addClass('showing');                    
      });          
    }
  });
});
```

Then change your CSS to position relative like so:

```
#cols {
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 400ms;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 600px;
  position:relative;
}
```

HTML (just add 'showing' class to first col):

```
<body>
   <button>Shift Cols & Focus Input</button>
   <div id="cols" col-to-show="1" >
      <div class="col showing" id="col-1">
        <input type="text" value="1" />
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="col-2">
        <input type="text" value="2" />
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="col-3">
        <input type="text" value="3" />
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tkk8f9/1/)

Comment: Sorry I know you used JSBin, but i prefer fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

> magically scrolls the input into view

This is the key. Just change `scrollLeft` of the container to `0` after focusing. I had to put a wrapper around it though.

http://jsbin.com/danarucama/1/edit?html,css,js,output